# Рейтинг фотографий

Tags: php

Написал сайт-конкурс фотографий. Юзверь регится на сайте, добавляет свои фотки. Победитель определяется по количеству голосов  (оценок) Осталось решить последнюю задачу: как сделать так, чтобы каждый юзверь мог смотреть своё положение в рейтинге судя по количеству оценок. Допустим, кто-то набрал максимальное кол-во оценок, например, 50. когда она нажимает на ссылку "Узнать мой рейтинг", он узнаёт, что он номер 1 и так далее

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*) as place from `scoreTable` where `score` > 50
```

А потом к place прибавить 1 - так получится место.

Comment: а структура таблицы какая?

Comment: Вам виднее. =)

Answer (score 0):

в чем тут могут быть проблему?

1. создаешь таблицу, в которой будет хранится:

айди фотографии,
 имя пользователя,
 сумма оценок,
 сумма голосов

1. по запросу выводишь результат на страницу

Comment: Ты случайно не кавказец?

Comment: нужно узнать рейтинг по отношению ко всем пользователям, а не кол-во своих оценок

Comment: ну какая разница? у тебя есть список оценок всех пользователей - выводи ТОП-10. Или если тебе надо "когда она нажимает на ссылку "Узнать мой рейтинг", он узнаёт, что он номер 1 и так далее", напиши условия, что-то типа, если рейтинг пользователя = максимальному в таблице, тогда он на 1 месте, или еще проще, храни результаты в массиве и выводи индекс массива, как номер места в рейтинге